# Registering multiple Amazon S3 Client

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

Here are the two interfaces I made for multiple S3 clients:

```
public interface IAmazonS3First : IAmazonS3
{

}

public interface IAmazonS3Second : IAmazonS3
{

}
```

In Program.cs, I have added following sdetup to set dependency injection:

```
var awsOption = configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    awsOption.Credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(configuration["FirstAccessKey"], configuration["FirstSecretKey"]);
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3First>(awsOption);


   awsOption = configuration.GetAWSOptions();
        awsOption.Credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(configuration["SecondAccessKey"], configuration["SecondSecretKey"]);
        services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3Second>(awsOption);
```

In target class, I want to make use of those two clients and have set up the following code:

```
    private readonly IAmazonS3First _s3FirstClient;
    private readonly IAmazonS3Second _s3SecondClient;


    public MyService(IAmazonS3First s3FirstClient, IAmazonS3Second s3SecondClient)
    {
        _s3FirstClient = s3FirstClient;
        _s3SecondClient = s3SecondClient;
```

Issue: When I am calling that service I am getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateConfig(Type serviceInterfaceType, AWSOptions options)
         at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateServiceClient(ILogger logger, Type serviceInterfaceType, AWSOptions options)
         at Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.ClientFactory.CreateServiceClient(IServiceProvider provider)
```

Can you share what I am doing wrong in adding that injection?

My goal is to use two different Amazon S3 clients (two different set of AWS Access Key/Secret Keys)